# Using get_it for a list parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, get-it

I don't know if i got the concept right for flutter and get_it as service locator. I wanna have MyApp in the service locator.

I have my main class

```
import 'di.dart' as di;

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  di.init();
  runApp(di.serviceLocator<MyApp>());
}
```

The di part should "assemble" the rest by itself. So in the di.dart i have

```
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<MyApp>(() => MyApp(widgets: serviceLocator()));
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<?whattoinserthere?>(() => [widget1, widget2, widget3, ...];
```

The MyApp class looks like

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<StatelessWidget>? widgets;

  const MyApp({super.key, this.widgets});

}
```

Since i wanna add widgets step by step while the application grows, i introduced a constructor param which is a list oft StatelessWidget ... when a new widget should be added, i wanna just add it to the list of widgets that is getting injected to the myApp widget

how to define this list in the di.dart, so that get_it can resolve it? The problem i see is, that List? is not a specific interface that is used as usually and therefore getting resolved to a concrete implementation.

What do i miss?

Comment: is a widget a service?

Comment: Probably not, but how to handle this params that are not a service? They have to be injected anyway ... i am a bit confused^^